# how to convert listview to recyclerview?

Tags: android

I have problem when I want to use these codes below and I use recyclerview in my code but I think its listview anybody can help me?

```
public ListViewSwipeGesture(RecyclerView listView, TouchCallbacks Callbacks, MainListFragment context){
    ViewConfiguration vc = ViewConfiguration.get(listView.getContext());
    mSlop = vc.getScaledTouchSlop();
    mMinFlingVelocity = vc.getScaledMinimumFlingVelocity() * 16;
    mMaxFlingVelocity = vc.getScaledMaximumFlingVelocity();
    mListView = listView;
    activity = context;
    tcallbacks = Callbacks;
    SwipeType = Double;
    GetResourcesValues();
```

when I use : mListview = listview;
I have an error.
and the error is :
Error:(103, 21) error: incompatible types: RecyclerView cannot be converted to ListView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not cast `ListView` into `RecyclerView`, As per the **Java**, 
Parent class can only hold reference of child object and also only you can cast a base class into it's child class (and that is only when child is `instanceof` that class).

So here listview and Recyclerview both don't have any relationship so you can not cast listview into recyclerview

Below is the class hierarchy of RecyclerView:

```
java.lang.Object
   ↳    android.view.View
       ↳    android.view.ViewGroup
           ↳    android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
```

Below is the class hierarchy of ListView:

```
java.lang.Object
   ↳    android.view.View
       ↳    android.view.ViewGroup
           ↳    android.widget.AdapterView<android.widget.ListAdapter>
               ↳    android.widget.AbsListView
                   ↳    android.widget.ListView
```